# "Merge" replacement Keras/Tensorflow/Python3

Tags: python, tensorflow, merge, keras, lstm

Merge is not running with Keras/Tensorflow/Python3 version. With previous versions, Merge was running.
But now, it is not running. So I think I should convert this code with replacement "Merge". "Merge" is missing in new Keras/Tensorflow/Python3 version.

How can I rewrite Merge(..., mode='ave') and Merge(...,mode='concat') ?

My code part is below :

```
...

from keras.layers import Merge
...
left_branch = Sequential()
left_branch.add(Convolution3D...
...
right_branch = Sequential()
right_branch.add(Convolution3D...
...
merged = Merge([left_branch, right_branch], mode='ave')
lstm_branch = Sequential()
lstm_branch.add(Embedding(input_dim=7, output_dim=8, input_length=7))
lstm_branch.add(LSTM(output_dim=8, input_shape=(7, ) ))
lstm_branch.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(merged)
merged_2 = Merge([model, lstm_branch], mode='concat')
model_2 = Sequential()
model_2.add(merged_2)
model_2.add(Dense(nb_classes,init='normal'))
model_2.add(Activation('softmax'))
model_2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Which error message do you get exactly? Please also format your code next time for more clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Merge has been replaced with Concatenate and Average,
It is a change in the new version of Keras. Now you should implement them like this

```
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate, Average   

layer_merge = Concatenate()( [layer1, layer2] )
layer_avg   = Average()( [layer1, layer2] )
```

The full documentation can be found [here](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#average)

Comment: OK, I will try.